# pullMediaFileListFromCamera keeps in UPDATING state on DJI MSDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to use the MSDK media manager to get photos on SD card. Everytime i shoot a photo on RC, MSDK automatically tries to update de media file list info, but after 20 minutes it keeps in UPDATING state. ¿What is the problem?

I thought it could be the large number of files on SD card, but i tried the app without that large amount of files on SD card and keep not working.

Everytime i shoot a photo i get this lines on the log:

constructor
setListener
MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400)
MediaPlayer::setAudioSessionId(17)
setDataSource(42, 58463500, 18254)
setVideoSurfaceTexture
prepare
message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
MediaPlayer::notify() prepared
signal application thread
callback application
prepare complete - status=0
back from callback
invoke 72
MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
start
invoke 72
message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
unrecognized message: (6, 0, 0)
callback application
back from callback
getCurrentPosition
message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
isPlaying: 1
unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
callback application
back from callback
message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
callback application
back from callback
message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
playback complete
callback application
back from callback
message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
callback application
back from callback
resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
setListener
disconnect
destructor
disconnect
mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
(co_j:1) updateMediaFileList false

then i tried to get the state of the update, and always get UPDATING